# How can I recover my email (in Thunderbird) from a failed hard drive?

Tags: data-recovery, thunderbird

My Windows hard drive failed and now I can not boot into Windows.

I have very important emails addressing financial information and must recover them! I've been able to boot from disk into Ubuntu, and gather files onto an external hard drive. I've done some searching but cant find and answers. So basically I have the MBOX file titled `INBOX` and the `INBOX.msf` file. How do I import these into Thunderbird? I tried copy/pasting them into the

> C:\Documents and Settings\Application Data\Thunderbird\Profiles\\Mail\Local Folders

directory, but Thunderbird ignored them. How can I recover my email?

Answer (score 1):

Basically you need to create a new user profile, decide what you want to move over, then copy in the the profile settings that were extracted from the failing drive.  I think depending on the version of Windows you were using the file locations may differ.

These links should have enough information to get you started:

[Help finding where your profiles are stored](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Moving_your_profile_folder)

[Finding what to copy over](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Moving_your_profile_folder)

Answer (score 0):

Okay instead of just the MBOX file and the .msf file what you need to do is copy everything. So under  ../profile/.default/(HERE).  Copy all of the stuff in that folder, on a different computer create a default profile. Then paste over anything that the new default folder created and walah!